Bypass "Your phone needs a SIM card to work" screen on a Moto G Play 2023 (Verizon)
I bought 2 Moto G Play 2023 phones off of eBay and I want to use them only with WiFi for development purposes. So I turn them on, and a little red bubble that says Hello pops up, and then a Verizon logo pops up. Then it goes to the screen with the Start button. I click that, then it wants me to insert a SIM card. There is no skip button, and when I try all the secret number codes in the Emergency Call section, they all are blocked saying that it is not an emergency number. There are some stickers on the back of the phones. Please ask me if you need them. So can someone please help me with this? Thanks! P.S. It runs Android 12.

I am aware of the 4 corners trick where you tap repeatedly on the screen with the "Start" button: upper left, upper right, lower right, lower left, and repeat? I found this video for Samsung: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQ2wUoScHr8 with the added "lower vol" button action. If it works do report back.

Unfortunately no that didn't work :(
